# Where to download Debian Puppet OVF file

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, puppet, vagrantfile

I need to have the puppetlabs/debian-8.2-64-puppet box for my virtualBox. However i don't have permissions to use url: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/puppetlabs/debian-8.2-64-puppet. I would appreciate if you could guide me how to find the OVF (Open Virtualization Format) file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL has moved: https://app.vagrantup.com/puppetlabs/boxes/debian-8.2-64-puppet

You don't need to find the OVF file, Vagrant will handle it for you.

You can also define it in your vagrantfile thusly:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "puppetlabs/debian-8.2-64-puppet"
end
```

Comment: The problem was that i had an older version of vagrant. I installed the new version and the problem was solved.